# How to modify SMSes in an Android inbox

Tags: android

How can I change the content of all or certain SMSes in my inbox?

Answer (score 1):

```
do {
    body.add(cursor.getString(3));
    values1.put("body", "Update 1" + cursor.getString(3));
    getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values1,
      "_id=" + cursor.getInt(0), null);
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
```